# Where to add Monitoring Reader role in Azure

Tags: azure, alert, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I want to setup some alerts in azure portal and now a bit confused about the "Monitoring Reader" and "Monitoring Contributor" roles.

Say, I have 2 web apps that belong to 1 resource group and both of them writing logs to 1 app insights instance. Now I want to add a new rule to app insights that when there are too many errors users who have the "Monitoring Reader" role shall receive an email.

Where do I need to grant user X this role? On the App Insights instance? On the Resource group or each of the Applications that might trigger those errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monitoring Contributor: Can read all monitoring data and **edit monitoring settings**.

Monitoring Reader: Can read all monitoring data (metrics, logs, etc.).

For more details about the two roles, please refer to: [Get started with roles, permissions, and security with Azure Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/roles-permissions-security#built-in-monitoring-roles)

And, as far as I know, you may assign the permission on the Application Insights instance, so that the user would be able to view the monitor data.

**Update:**

I create 2 function apps with same application insights instance. A guest user was invited and assigned with the Monitoring Reader role. The guest user can view all the 2 function apps' monitoring data.[image]

Comment: So if I, for example, want to separate alerts for those 2 apps I will need to create 2 separate instances of app insights?

Comment: @JleruOHeP Based on my test, if a user was assigned the permission on the Application insights, he will be able to view all the monitoring data of all the instances. If you want to separate the t apps strictly, you may need to create 2 separate instances of app insights.